# Reload opengl textures after onResume() in GLSurfaceView

Tags: android, opengl-es

I have an android application with 2 activities, A and B. The application starts with A, then I tap the screen to switch to B. B appears correctly, then i press the back button on my phone to switch back to A. Now the activity runs correctly, except i can't see my textures. The activity's onResume method calls the GLSurfaceView's onResume method, it calls my renderer's on onSurfaceCreated, then the onSurfaceChanged. After this onDrawFrame called on every frame, but it only clears the screen with the given color. I know that GLSurfaceView's onPause destroys it's content, and onResume should rebuild it, but it wouldn't work for me:(

My code:

The renderer:

```
public class GlRenderer implements Renderer {

private Context     context;
private CScene      scene;
long mLastTime;

public GlRenderer(Context context, CScene scene) {
    this.context = context;
    this.scene=scene;
}

@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();

    if (mLastTime > now) return;
    float dt = (float) ((now - mLastTime) / 1000.0);
    mLastTime = now;
    scene.Update(dt);
    scene.Draw(gl);
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
    if(height == 0) {                       //Prevent A Divide By Zero By
        height = 1;                         //Making Height Equal One
    }
    gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);     //Reset The Current Viewport
    gl.glLoadIdentity();                    //Reset The Projection Matrix
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);    //Select The Projection Matrix

    GLU.gluOrtho2D(gl, 0, width, height, 0);

    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);     //Select The Modelview Matrix
    gl.glLoadIdentity();    //Reset The Modelview Matrix

    scene.LoadTextures(gl);
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);            //Enable Texture Mapping ( NEW )
    gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);            //Enable Smooth Shading
    gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f);    //Black Background
    gl.glClearDepthf(1.0f);                     //Depth Buffer Setup
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);            //Enables Depth Testing
    gl.glDepthFunc(GL10.GL_LEQUAL);             //The Type Of Depth Testing To Do

    gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_NICEST);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND); 
    gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_ONE, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA); 
}
```

}

My Sprite class:

```
public class Sprite {

private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;   // buffer holding the vertices

private FloatBuffer textureBuffer;  // buffer holding the texture coordinates
private float texture[] = new float[8]; 
/** The texture pointer */
private int[] textures = new int[1];

private float width;
private float height;
private float x;
private float y;

public Sprite(float _width, float _height, float xpos, float ypos){
    this(_width,_height,xpos,ypos,1.0f,1.0f);
}

public Sprite(float _width, float _height, float xpos, float ypos, float tex_width, float tex_height) {
    //.......
}

public void loadGLTexture(GL10 gl, Context c, Bitmap bitmap) {
    // generate one texture pointer
    gl.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);
    // ...and bind it to our array
    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);

    // create nearest filtered texture
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);

    // Use Android GLUtils to specify a two-dimensional texture image from our bitmap 
    GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);

    // Clean up
    bitmap.recycle();
}

public void draw(GL10 gl) {
    // bind the previously generated texture
    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);

    // Point to our buffers
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    // Set the face rotation
    gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CW);
    // Point to our vertex buffer
    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
    gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, textureBuffer);

    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    gl.glTranslatef((float)x, (float)y, 0);

    // Draw the vertices as triangle strip
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0,4);

    //Disable the client state before leaving
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
}
```

}

My Scene class:

```
public class CScene{
Context context;
public String name;

    protected Activity activity;

    public CScene(Context _context, Activity activity, String name){
        context=_context;
        this.name=name;
        this.activity=activity;
    }


    public void Update(float dt){

    }
    public void Draw(GL10 gl){
    }

    public boolean TapControl(MotionEvent  event)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void LoadTextures(GL10 gl) {

    }
}
```

The structure of my application:
Each activity has one GLSurfaceView, and every GLSurfaceView contains a custom Scene. The activity first creates the Scene, which calls the constructor of the sprites. Then the activity creates the GLSurfaceView, which calls the scene's LoadTextures method (from onSurfaceChagned), where its load the bitmap for the sprites on the scene with loadGLTexture. Then the renderer of the GlSurfaceView call the scene's Draw method in onDrawFrame, and the scene's Draw method calls the Sprite's Draw method.

// Sorry for my poor english

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally figured out, these lines in the renderer's onSurfaceChanged mehotd are out of order:

```
gl.glLoadIdentity();                    //Reset The Projection Matrix
gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);    //Select The Projection Matrix
```

If i change their order everything works great.